# Conditionally add HTML element attribute in Facelets

Tags: jsf, facelets

Using Facelets and writing some XHTML, I cannot figure out how to create an element and then add attributes later, like in xslt if you wanted to conditionally add an attribute:

```
<xsl:element name="div">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">color:blue;</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Google gave some examples with JSP taglib similar to

```
<jsp:element name="div">
     <jsp:attribute name=".">...</jsp:attribute>
</jsp:element>
```

That library is not provided as standard in Facelets and searching the docs of the ones that are included doesn't show anything obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `<c:if><f:attribute>` on a real JSF component.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block">
    <c:if test="#{bean.condition}"><f:attribute name="style" value="color:blue;"/></c:if>
</h:panelGroup>
```

By the way, you should really be using fullworthy CSS classes in CSS stylesheet files instead of tight-coupling `style` attributes over all place in markup.

You could conditionally declare style classes as below:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="#{bean.condition ? 'foo' : 'bar'}" />
```

Comment: isn't the use of the **c:** tags now deprecated?

Comment: @AlanObject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: Is there also a solution, if the `<h:panelGroup>` would be inside a `<ui:repeat>` and the condition is depending on the iteration-variable? You can't use `<c:if>` in this case due to problems with build/render view time.